# Removing elements from an object with changing indexes

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble deleting rules from the stylesheet object due to ever changing indexes.

I have this function:

```
function delete_styles(delete_array){

    console.log(delete_array); // ["0,0", "0,1", "0,2", "0,6", "0,7", "0,8", "0,9", "0,10", "0,14", "0,15", "0,16"]

    for(var i in delete_array){

        var pair = delete_array[i].split(',');
        var p1 = parseInt(pair[0]);
        var p2 = parseInt(pair[1]);

        document.styleSheets[p1].deleteRule(p2);

    }
}
```

However, as soon as I delete `(0,0)`, the index `(0,1)` is invalid because it becomes `(0,0)`!

I can't just use a counter and take a way an incrementing amount each time because there may be larger gaps in the CSS rules.

Any help on the logic here?

Comment: Since you should not use `for...in` to iterate over arrays anyway, use a normal `for` loop and iterate over the array in reverse order.

Comment: @FelixKling you should've put that in an answer.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider starting from the end, instead of the beginning, and work your way down. That way, the there are no styles falling on the spot you just deleted.

Also, when using the array, do not use `for in`. use the usual `for` loop (or `while`) instead.

```
var i = delete_array.length;
while(i--){
    var pair = delete_array[i].split(',');
    var p1 = parseInt(pair[0]);
    var p2 = parseInt(pair[1]);

    document.styleSheets[p1].deleteRule(p2);
}
```

Comment: Beauty is really in simplicity!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop:

```
var pair;
while (pair = delete_array.shift()) {
    pair = pair.split(',');
    var p1 = parseInt(pair[0]);
    var p2 = parseInt(pair[1]);
    document.styleSheets[p1].deleteRule(p2);    
}
```

Comment: The problem is not only with the loop, it's rather that `document.styleSheets[p1].deleteRule(p2)` removes elements such the the remaining indexes in the array become invalid.